# How can I provide default value when a value is undefined?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I can use the `||` operator to provide a default value anywhere when a given value is undefined or null

```
let a = maybeUndefinedValue || 'my default value'
foo(arg1, arg2 || 'default', arg3)
bar = settings.getSync('key') || 'default value'
```

However, this would not work for booleans, as both a `false` and an `undefined` value would trigger the default value to be used. For example, I want to use the default value only when the settings is missing, but not when the settings is set to false. If I use

```
let mySettings = settings.getSync('aBooleanKey') || true
```

Even when the settings is present and is set to false, it'll still fall back to `true`. I could use

```
let mySettings = settings.getSync('aBooleanKey') == undefined ? true : settings.getSync('aBooleanKey')
```

But this feels extra as I'm calling the function twice. Is there an elegant solution to ***providing a default value ONLY when it's undefined and not false*** in Javascript just like the `||` operator? By elegant I mean I don't have to call the function twice or use an intermediate variable.

Comment: you can use the [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) to check only undefined and null

Comment: `const a = whatever() ?? defaultValue`